# mysql error 1406

Tags: mysql

I have created a database & am trying to load data from a spreadsheet csv file. There is no data in it yet. When I run

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'docs.csv' INTO list FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (vendor, title, project, description, shelf);
```

I get a message "**ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'vendor' at row 1**". The vendor entry at row 1 is 6 characters long though. I created my table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE list (
    autonumber  SERIAL,
    vendor      varchar(50),
    title       varchar(100),
    project     varchar(100),
    description     text,
    shelf       smallint UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY(autonumber));
```

There are commas & carriage returns (Alt + Enter in the spreadsheet)in many entries in the description column; am I right in using \t for the FIELDS TERMINATED command & will the carriage returns cause trouble?

Comment: You're specifying that the fields are terminated by a tab character - is this the actual separator in the CSV file? It looks like the separator is not being found and mySQL is attempting to insert everything into the vendor column as a result

Comment: As a spreadsheet, tab obviously moves from one cell to the next, that is to say each field is in a seperate cell. If I open the doc in a text editor it shows "Jacobs,Summary Report,New Plant Introduction Project,...", - each entry seems to be seperated by a comma. In the Description field though, there are commas in common use.

Comment: Even though they are used they will have been escaped, most likely by being enclosed in `"` characters. See @Tom's answer to let mySQL know about this.

Answer (score 0):

the value is too long for this column

try change from 50 to 100 as this

```
     CREATE TABLE list (
     autonumber  SERIAL,
     vendor      varchar(100),
     title       varchar(100),
     project     varchar(100),
     description     text,
     shelf       smallint UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY(autonumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think having carriage return characters in you fields will cause trouble because your line separator is \n.  A carriage return in a field will be taken as the end of the record I believe.  If you can add quoted identifiers to your fields, that might help.

You would need to add this clause to your infile statement:

```
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the complete path of the infile and do your code as following.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'docs.csv' INTO TABLE list

 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 

 ENCLOSED BY '"' 

 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (vendor, title, project, description, shelf);
```

Give the path of the infile just like the following example..

```
load data local infile 'c:/xampp/htdocs/example.csv'

     into table mytbl fields terminated by ','

     enclosed by '"'

     lines terminated by '\r\n' 

     ignore 1 lines (f_name,age,id);
```

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your csv file encoding is not same as mysql character set, this will also lead to ***"ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'vendor' at row 1"***.

for example, if you mysql character set is GBK, while you csv file is encoded in UTF-8, then it will lead to the same error when load.

just change you file encoding to the same as mysql character set.