# Error 1064 - Optionally Enclosed By ' " '

Tags: mysql

After posting my question on the Error 1406 which I was getting when loading data into my MySQL db from a file ([mysql error 1406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505699/mysql-error-1406)) I saw that I was saving my raw data spreadsheet as a comma seperated file rather than a tab seperated file. I have now corrected this.

Tom had made the point in his reply to the previous question that, as there are carriage returns in some entries in the data, I would need to enclose them with inverted commas, " ". In the spreadsheet I created a new column & used the formula =CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34) to surround the cell text with "   ", formatted it so it keeps its text & removed the original column. Checked it with a text editor & all looks good to go.

When I use the command:

```
mysql> load data infile 'docs.txt'into table list fields terminated by '\t' lines
terminated by '\n' optionally enclosed by '"' (vendor, title, id, part, project, 
description, machine, shelf, compartment, name, checkout);
```

I get an error message of:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'optionally       enclosed by '"' (vendor, title, id, part, project, description,
machi' at line 1
```

Can anyone help please. 
**Just to say thanks for the assistance received in other questions so far. Im very impressed with the speed & helpfullness of the responses on this forum

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

check this for example which i copied from the follwing link:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name (column1,column2)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

[see here for syntax](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-use-mysql-fast-load-data-for-updates-1753.html)

Comment: list is the name of my table. I entered the command as above, but get the following response:
mysql> load data infile 'cardex02.txt;into table list (vendor, title, id, part, project, description, machine, shelf, compartment, name, checkout)
    '> fields terminated by '\t'
Outfile disabled.
    '>

Comment: OK had typo in the command above, should read, 'cardex02.txt' INTO TABLE. When I enter this though I get:   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fields terminated by '\t' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'' at line 2